# How can I dual boot with an Asus G55VW?

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia, dual-boot, wubi

I just bought a new Asus G55VW ROG notebook. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 8 without success.

I tried several different things:

1. I installed from Windows using wubi. Now in win boot loader I get
   Win 8 and Ubuntu but Ubuntu won't load (I get an black error screen
   about wubildr)
2. I tried installing Ubuntu from a live-USB but Ubuntu wouldn't load the desktop environment, just a command line.
3. So I tried to install Ubuntu without trying it before and the installer run "smoothly" (with GUI). After rebooting the PC, I get to the grub menu,  and I have all the options: Ubuntu, recovery, Win 8, etc. The problem is that Ubuntu still won't load the desktop environment.
4. I tried installing the nvidia-current drivers from the command line but it keeps complaining about held back packages and missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, connect your computer to an Ethernet cable so that you can access the Internet.

In GRUB, go to "Advanced Options for Ubuntu."
You will find a few options there. At least one of these options will be marked (recovery mode.) Go to it, and press enter.

If you get an image on your screen that looks purple with white streaks going across it, and nothing has happened in over a minute, than your computer has decided that it is going to do nothing. You have to force your computer off and try again.

When you get through all of the rushing command line deal, you will get to a menu. The first button on this menu is "Resume." Press it.

You may have to wait up to a minute to log in, but you will have a desktop environment, although it may be sluggish and sometimes be unresponsive.

After you log in, go to the menu and search for "Software Sources." A button saying Software Sources will pop up. Press it. It will take a few moments for the window to appear, but when it does, you will see a tab on the top of the window that says "Additional Drivers." Click on it.

In this window, you will see a few devices, up to and including your graphics card and your wi-fi receiver. Start with your graphics card. Download a proprietary driver for your graphics by pressing the one you want, pressing the apply button, entering your password and waiting for the driver to download. When the download is complete, you may as well get the wi-fi driver for your netbook. Click on the driver you want, apply, password, wait.

When you finish downloading your drivers, restart. You should be able to log into "Ubuntu" in GRUB without any problems now.